# ClassNotFoundException when running self compiled Browser

Tags: java, android, exception

I compiled latest AOSP browser and it compiled it without any problem.
When I launch it I have a ClassNotFoundException.

I'm using latest SDK 17, but the project doesn't have a lib folder or external jar, so it looks like it's not the usual problem.

Haven't touched anything **except from the package name** in every file (because it noticed there's already the browser with the same package com.android.browser in the same phone).

Logcat:

```
08-03 17:18:32.116: E/Trace(30047): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-03 17:18:32.194: D/AndroidRuntime(30047): Shutting down VM
08-03 17:18:32.194: W/dalvikvm(30047): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a7d300)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application it.androidhd.jbrowser.Browser: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.androidhd.jbrowser.Browser
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4275)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4896)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.androidhd.jbrowser.Browser
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:967)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
08-03 17:18:32.194: E/AndroidRuntime(30047):    ... 11 more
```

Screenshot:
http://s18.postimage.org/qi5f3zkfd/Cattura.png

Comment: you want to access `Browser` class of another app ?

Comment: On the same app, I want to recompile the browser app.

Comment: Are you sure the class exists?

Comment: yes ->http://s18.postimage.org/qi5f3zkfd/Cattura.png

Comment: The project seems not to show compilation error. I've already tried closing eclipse and cleaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention when you import things into Eclipse using automated tools. Recreating the project from scratch will do the work.